# Save a user token in multi user Rails app with Ruby Thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

In our multi_user Rails 4.2 app, there is a need to save a user token when a user logs in. Here is a solution I am thinking of by adding two methods in `User` model with ruby thread:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current_token=(token)
     Thread.current[:current_token] = token
  end

  def self.current_token
     Thread.current[:current_token]
  end
end
```

When a user logging in, his/her token is assigned by `@user.current_token = token` (assume token has been generated). Late in the app, the `current_token` can be retrieved by `User.current_token`

I am new to ruby thread and there are a couple of things to confirm:

```
1. is token above thread safe and will never be changed (by another user, or overwritten by another user's token) during the `@user`'s session lifetime?
2. is `User.current_token` available everywhere inside the Rails app (as long as `User` is accessible)?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Although the thread local writing is threadsafe, I would not count on it never being changed. Some servers will clear thread locals after requests are finished. See: https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/61294479b2f77a838f0d91064ca6d4ed5ba4b9ff/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb#L48
2. `User.current_token` will be available everywhere in the app the constant User is loaded.

I would not recommend this approach to storing a token. I would encourage you to explicitly pass the token to whoever needs it. This makes the code:

1. Easier to test (you dont have to stub out a thread local on the User class)
2. Code is easier to reason about. You know exactly where the token is coming from.
3. Less prone to unexpected strange threading bugs

Comment: We tried to pass token in session. However MVC model discourages the use of session in model.

Comment: I need to understand a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish here. What is the purpose of storing the token in this case?

Comment: It would be bad if web server starts to clean up the thread local on its own. Token is used to distinguish user from group to group (let's s say company). It is not user specific but group specific. So token is used to retrieve information in model which belongs to certain group.